# "You must be logged in to comment" but I am already logged in

Tags: multisite, comments

- Latest WP running on RHEL 6.10
- PHP version 7.2.21
- MySQL is old and should be updated, but I doubt it's the reason.

I have a Multisite setup going. I have a primary, call it blog.world.com, with a number of sub-sites. Commenting works on most of these sites. I haven't checked them all, but it works on the primary and others I have checked, except for 2 that I know of.

On those 2, I am logged in as a super admin, and when I try to comment, I get a message saying "You must be logged in to comment".

There are only 3 plugins running:

- Active Directory Integration for Intranet Sites
- Classic Editor
- Import and Export Users and Customers

The theme on these 2 sites is Antisnews

“Allow people to submit comments on new posts” is checked

“Users must be registered and logged in to comment (Signup has been disabled. Only members of this site can comment.)” is checked

Not sure what else I should check.

Any ideas what the issue may be? The site has its own admin, so maybe they changed something?

Comment: The common item here seems to be the theme; have you asked on the Antinews theme's official support channels?

Comment: I had thought of that, the only thing stopping me is that there is another sub using the same theme, and it is ok. However, that doesn't always mean much.

Comment: So, I've been looking into this theme, and so far, have not found a way to contact its author: antisocialmediallc.com The site comes up, in Indonesian, with no contact info.